# How can I set a color to just some characters of one word?

Tags: html, css, persian

First of all, I'm talking about Persian language .. Noted that it is a rtl language.

Here is my current word:

```
سلامتی
```

As you see, all Persian characters are adhered (stick) together. Now I need to set *red* color to 4 first characters. Something like this:

```css
span{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<span>سلام</span>تی
```

As you see, when I set *red* color to some character, the word will be two different partitions .. while the whole of that is a single word and all characters should stick to each other *(like `سلامتی`)*.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

in this case you have to insert a ***zero-width joiner*** `&zwj;` at the end of the content that you want join it to other.

like this:

```css
.red{color:red;}
```

```html
<span class="red">سلام&zwj;</span>تى
```

Answer (score -1):

it's the white space that set apart your word
so you can try this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="red">سلام</span>   <span>تی<span>
</div>
```

css will be like

```
.wrapper {font-size:0}
.wrapper span{font-size:12px;}
.wrapper .red{color:red;}
```

hope this helps

Comment: try this
`.wrapper span{font-size:12px;float:left;}`

Answer (score -1):

you can specify a style: `<span style="color: red;">سلام</span>تی`

or better:

```
    <span class="color_red">سلام</span>تی
    <style>
    .color_red {
      color: red;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
    }
    </dtyle>
```

Comment: u can try letter-spacing: -1px;

Answer (score -1):

You can use inline style sheet

```
<p style="color:green">Hello</p>
<p style="color:red">World!</p>
```